# Average Current vs Arithmetic Average

Tags: current, charge

I am just starting to learn the theory of electronics.

Coming from a probability and statistics background I have a very deeply ingrained idea of the term *average*.

The average to me is the [Arithmetic Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean). In other words, if I was to take a sample from whatever data I calculated my mean from I have a pretty good chance of seeing a value near the *mean*.

It seems this definition is not the same in electrical engineering. The *average* current is defined by the change in charge over the change in time. This is similar to the physical velocity. But there is no averaging here being done at all, is there? You aren't summing anything in the numerator, instead you are dividing the change in charge by the change in time. This would give you the amount of charge changed per unit time.

Imagine I was to draw a charge value from a list of charge values measured from a circuit. If I naively assumed *average* meant the above I would expected any given charge measurement to be dispersed somewhere near the value there. However, in reality the *Average Charge* defines the slope of a line.

How can I reconcile these two things so I can really understand what *average* means here?

*EDIT*:

After sitting with paper for a while justifying it to myself there is a single case that confuses me:

Let's use this data set:

`Q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`
`t = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

and we have the following data points

`(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 4)`

Finding the average current between t = 0 and t = 4 is:

`4 - 0 / 4 - 0 = 1 C/s = 1A`

However, using arithmetic mean:

`1/5 * (0 + 1 + 3 + 2 + 4) = 2A`.

The final value at time `t = 4` where `Q = 4` is throwing the calculation off.

Comment: *"The average current is defined by the change in charge over the change in time."* Where did you get that from?

Comment: *The average current is defined by the change in charge over the change in time.* If the charge = 0 at time = 0 then this definition is the same as the Arithmetic average. I do not see how you think EEs treat an Average value any different from what you're used to. Because: we don't.

Comment: @Oldfart Practical Electronics for Inventors - section 2.2 - The definition of average current.

Comment: These upvoted comments aren't helping me. I can see how the arithmetic mean of Q between two points is equal to (Q - Q_0)/2 (since n = 2) but I don't see how in general they are equal.

Comment: That is not the definition I have lived with. It just coulombs/sec.

Comment: This definition is correct, it just means that if current is inconsistent over a period of time examined, the average current will be equivalent to the area under the graph of current divided by time, this is basically the definition of the Arithmetic average, as @Bimpelrekkie was saying.  There is, however the effective (RMS) voltage, which is another average voltage separate from the actual average voltage that we use to make DC formulas work out with AC circuits.

Comment: @KH Thank you for your reply. I've left another note on my thought process and exactly where I am getting confused.

Comment: The arithmetic mean is the absolute value of the average over that time, and there may not be any chance at all (for instance in square wave PWM) to see a value near the average in the sample.  If you have a 5V 50% duty cycle square wave, the average voltage will be 2.5V but you would have to measure during the instant the circuit switches to measure 2.5V.  So the other two averages, the median, and the mode, refer more to the frequency with which you'll see a given number.

Comment: @KH So is the reason I am confused right now because my sample data (in the edit) is modeled by a periodic-looking function so the average is screwed up when I measure it from t = 0 to 4 due to the cycling that happens in the middle?

Comment: Errr hold on I haven't even looked at that part yet.

Comment: the last formulation makes no sense to me. what are those numbers?

Comment: @Jasen just data from a graph I drew to graphically illustrate this concept to myself. I should be able to plot the secant line between two points and prove to myself the slope is indeed equal to the average current.

Comment: @CL40 Ok I see...  In the part that you added, you use the arithmetic mean.  When you do so, you are calculating the "change in charge over the change in time".  If you imagine that instead of 5 samples in your 2 second time frame you had infinite samples, no matter how convoluted the graph of current was you would get the correct average.

Comment: I see @KH that if I start sampling at smaller and smaller intervals it begins to approach the arithmetic mean. It takes a lot of samples though, I wrote down around 30 and it started getting a little closer. I suppose I can see now that if you extended the samples to infinity you'd eventually see it fall back to the arithmetic mean. I guess the answer is that the arithmetic mean with too few samples is very choppy (like in probability). It seems the mean value theorem is useful here. If you could post this with some math showing the equality in the limit I'd happily mark this answered.

Comment: In your "statistics" definition of average you consider a **value** at a **point**. That's what I would call "time discrete". The data values change abruptly between each point. However the flow of electrons (current) is a **time continuous** process.

Comment: RE "if I was to take a sample from whatever data I calculated my mean from I have a pretty good chance of seeing a value near the mean." No statistician would claim that as a general rule. Consider bimodal distributions, for example.

Comment: @ThePhoton I was just stating a simplification because I didn't expect people frequenting this place to be familiar with all the peculiarities of distributions. You're completely missing my point in the question by focusing on that one nitpick of my explanation.

Comment: @Oldfart Coulombs/second is instantaneous current, not average current. They are only the same if the current is constant.

Comment: @CL40, I realize it's not your main point, and that's why I made a comment rather than an answer. But it's a glaring enough error to make me (and maybe others) skeptical of where you say you come from a "statistics background".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is rate of change of charge with respect to time. Your example shows that charge changes 1 coulomb per second therefore the current is 1 amp. When you integrate (sum) the charge values you get 10 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4). Taking that value of ten and calculating the mean (by dividing by 5) tells you that the average charge was 2 coulombs, it doesn't tell you what the current is.

Answer (score 1):

A current of 1A means that 1 coulomb worth of electrons has gone past a given point in 1 second.

The electrical definition of average is just the same as everybody else's.  You are just calculating the arithmetic mean wrong.  You are mixing up the total charge that has gone past so far with the amount of charge that has gone by in just the last second.  If you are going for the approach of adding up and dividing by the number of samples, you need to record just the charge that has gone by since the last sample.

And don't assume that if you just take a reading at random, that it will be anywhere near the average.  As an extreme case, consider what happens if you connect a 50 ohm resistor across the output of a signal generator set to produce a 5V square wave.  Half the time, the current will be 5/50 = 0.1A.  Half the time it will be 0/50 = 0.0A.  The average current will be 0.05A, but you will never actually see that current however often you measure it.

Answer (score 0):

your final formulation is not computing mean current, it is computing mean charge.

Answer (score 0):

Average current.
If, by means of a rectifier, the direction of the alternating current is reversed every half period, so that a periodic current is obtained, but with alternations all in the same direction, and if we pass it through an electrolytic bath, the amount of decomposed electrolyte or substance deposited in a given time will be the same as that decomposed or deposited by a direct current of intensity equal to the average intensity of the rectified alternating current, which is why this value is sometimes called average electrolytic intensity.

Comment: *average electrolytic intensity* Can you provide a source for this?

Comment: @MiNiMe Early metering comes to mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter#Direct_current I'm not sure about the term, myself; might it be a direct translation of a term more familiar elsewhere?

Comment: @TimWilliams Might be. It doesn't sound like something being taught in modern EE teachings, unless it's like you say. I hope manuel Peñascoso reply.